Switch camera sensors automatically to keep image clarity in flutter camera
I'm trying to implement image capture in my flutter app using the camera package. The issue I'm running into is I'm noticing that you have to select a single sensor to preview/capture from. This is causing issues on newer iPhones that have 3 rear cameras and have a tough time with focus close up and longer distance capture. Doing a direct comparison with the native iOS camera app, its clear that there is more going on there to keep the image quality up no matter what you're pointing the camera at. Our app needs to be able to capture close up shots as well as objects that are further away and a user shouldnt need to cycle through their various cameras to get the most clear shot.
Auto-focus mode is on also: _controller.setFocusMode(FocusMode.auto);
Does anyone have any tips or tricks for fixing this issue?
